# How to write a generic webgl render loop while binding vertex array objects and buffer data for dynamic draw on render time?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, webgl

I want to display text using the mentioned method in [this article](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-text-glyphs.html). Meanwhile I care about code to be generic.

In the article it mentions manually creating a buffer info which I call first method:

```
// Maunally create a bufferInfo
var textBufferInfo = {
  attribs: {
    a_position: { buffer: gl.createBuffer(), numComponents: 2, },
    a_texcoord: { buffer: gl.createBuffer(), numComponents: 2, },
  },
  numElements: 0,
};
var textVAO = twgl.createVAOFromBufferInfo(
    gl, textProgramInfo, textBufferInfo);
```

and setup render using:

```
// update the buffers
textBufferInfo.attribs.a_position.numComponents = 2;
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, textBufferInfo.attribs.a_position.buffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.arrays.position, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, textBufferInfo.attribs.a_texcoord.buffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.arrays.texcoord, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

opposed to this second method:

```
// Create data for 'F'
var fBufferInfo = twgl.primitives.create3DFBufferInfo(gl);
var fVAO = twgl.createVAOFromBufferInfo(
    gl, fProgramInfo, fBufferInfo);
```

and setup render:

```
// setup the attributes and buffers for the F
gl.bindVertexArray(fVAO);
```

So I thought this means, on initialization time, I can setup a VAO like this:

```
const makeVao = (bufferInfos) => {
  let vao = gl.createVertexArray();
  gl.bindVertexArray(vao);

  bufferInfos.forEach(({
    array,
    size,
    index
  }) => {

    let buffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);

    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(array), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(index);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(index,
                           size,
                           gl.FLOAT,
                           false,
                           0,
                           0);

  });

  gl.bindVertexArray(null);

  return vao;
};
```

With `bufferInfos` usage:

```
let bufferInfos = [{
  array: [vertices],
  size: 2,
  index: gl.getAttribLocation(program, name) 
}];
```

This will setup attributes and give me a VAO that I can use at render time like:

```
gl.bindVertexArray(vao);
```

then I am done.

Except, I want the first method, where I can set vertices attributes on each render. So how do I set up the generic code to be able to set shader attributes on render time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using vertex array objects you only need to setup attributes at init time. Attributes keep a pointer to the buffer that was current when `vertexAttribPointer` was called. See [this article on attribute state](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-attributes.html) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28641368/128511) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27148273/what-is-the-logic-of-binding-buffers-in-webgl/27164577)

In other words if you do this

```
// assume positionLoc = 0, normalLoc = 1, texcoordLoc = 2

gl.bindVertexArray(someVAO);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLoc, ...);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(normalLoc, ...);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texcoordLoc);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(texcoordLoc, ...);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texcoordLoc);
```

Then `someVAO` holds the following state

```
// pseudo code
someVAO = {
  attributes: [
    { enabled: true, buffer: positionBuffer, ... },  // loc = 0
    { enabled: true, buffer: normalBuffer, ... },    // loc = 1
    { enabled: true, buffer: texcoordBuffer, ... },  // loc = 2
    { enabled: false, ... },                         // loc = 3
    ...
  ]
  elementArrayBuffer: null,  
}
```

So anytime you want to update a buffer just

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferToUpdate);
gl.bindData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, newData, gl.???_DRAW);
```

or

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferToUpdate);
gl.bindSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, newData);
```

And anytime you want to render you just

```
gl.useProgram(someProgram);
gl.bindVertexArray(someVAO)
gl.uniform... // for each uniform
gl.drawXXX
```

The only complication is that if you try to use the same vertex array with 2 or more programs you need to make sure the attribute locations match for both programs. You can do that either by assigning locations manually in the vertex shader GLSL

```
#version 300 es
layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 normal;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 texcoord;
```

Or **before** calling `gl.linkProgram` you can call `gl.bindAttribLocation` as in

```
gl.bindAttribLocation(someProgram, 0, "position");
gl.bindAttribLocation(someProgram, 1, "normal");
gl.bindAttribLocation(someProgram, 2, "texcoord");
gl.linkProgram(someProgram);
```

I prefer the second method is it's more [D.R.Y.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) but the first method is more common I'm only guessing because D.R.Y. style programming is also less common than non-D.R.Y.

If you're using twgl to compile your programs you can pass in the locations for it to call `bindAttribLocation` for you

```
const programOptions = {
  attribLocations: {
    'position': 0,
    'normal':   1,
    'texcoord': 2,
    'color':    3,
  },
};
const programInfo1 = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs1, fs1], programOptions);
const programInfo2 = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs2, fs2], programOptions);
```

As for your code, the only issue I can see with your `makeVAO` function is you're not storing `buffer` for each attribute anywhere so you have no easy way to call `gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, theBufferToUpdate)` when you want to try to update a buffer. Otherwise, at a glance, your `makeVAO` function looks fine.

you could for example do this

```
const makeVao = (bufferInfos) => {
  let vao = gl.createVertexArray();
  gl.bindVertexArray(vao);

  bufferInfos.forEach((bufferInfo) => {
    const {
        array,
        size,
        index
      } = bufferInfo;
    const buffer = gl.createBuffer();
    bufferInfo.buffer = buffer;         // remember the buffer
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);

    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(array), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(index);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(index,
                           size,
                           gl.FLOAT,
                           false,
                           0,
                           0);

  });

  gl.bindVertexArray(null);

  return vao;
};
```

and now you could use

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferInfos[0].buffer);
gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, newData);
```

To update the first buffer.

Comment: Can't seem to find gl.bindData() nor gl.bindSubData()? Are you refering to gl.bufferData() and gl.bufferSubData(), is this part of the pseudo code or am I completely missing something?